# Prove that $int(\partial A)$ is empty.

Tags: general-topology

> Prove that $int(\partial A)$ is empty.

Is this always true? By definition the boundary is closed since $\partial A= cl(A) \cap cl(A)^c$ and this is the intersection of two closed sets.

So is it true that the interior of closed set is empty?

I get that $int(\partial A)=int(cl(A) \cap cl(A)^c) = int(cl(A)) \cap int(cl(A)^c) = int(cl(A)) \setminus int(cl(A)^c)^c$

If the complement distributes I get $int(\partial A) = int(cl(A)) \setminus int(cl(A)^c)^c = int(cl(A)) \setminus int(cl(A)) = \emptyset$?

Comment: $cl(A^c)$, not $cl(A)^c$.

Comment: Consider the normal topology on $\mathbb{R}$. What's the boundary of the rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: @BrandonduPreez It’s the empty set.

Comment: The interior of a closed set is not in general empty. Take for instance $[0,1]$ in the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @JimingLe No. The closure of $\mathbb{Q}$ is $\mathbb{R}$. The closure of the irrationals (which is the complement of the rationals) is *also* $\mathbb{R}$. So $\partial(\mathbb{Q}) = \mathbb{R}$, which does not have empty interior.

Answer (score 5):

This is wrong. A counter-example is $(\partial \Bbb{Q})^o=\Bbb{R}$.